# DropDownListFor with ViewBag does not pass values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to pass a new booking via a create view where the user can select different locations. I can select the locations in the view, but the location attribute is still set to null, when I click submit, everything else works.

The locations are stored in a List in an infrastructure model, I am guessing, the problem is, that my values are LocationIds and not Location objects, but I don't know how to create an selected list with object values, since all the examples are with ids/names.

These are my models:

```
public class Infrastructure
    {
        public int InfrastructureId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public List<Location> Locations { get; set; }

}

public class Location
{
        
    public int LocationId { get; set; }

    public Address Address { get; set; }

    public int CountEmployee { get; set; }

    public GPS Coordinates { get; set; }

    public List<ChargingStation> ChargingStations { get; set; }

}
```

this is the Create in the Controller:

```
public IActionResult Create()
        {
            Infrastructure infrastructure = _infrastructure.GetRealInfrastructure();
            List<Location> locations = infrastructure.Locations;
            ViewBag.Locations = new SelectList(locations, "LocationId", "Address.City");
            return View();
        }
```

and this is the view:

```
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="end" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="end" class="form-control" id="endTime"/>
                    <span asp-validation-for="end" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-3">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="location" class="control-label"></label>
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.location, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Locations, "Choose Location", new { @class = "form-control" })                       
                    <span asp-validation-for="location" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
```

The values for endtime for example are saved, but location is still set too null, so I am guessing I am missing some select/submit tag? Or as written before its because I pass an string value (LocationId) instead of an actual location object?

Comment: If you need only in locationid from the drop-down list then you should change property to `public int LocationId {get;set;}` and change dropdownlistfor in view to `model => model.LocationId`

Comment: Are there values in the location drop down ?

Comment: Yes, it shows me all the citys I have in my Infrastructure Location List, I can also select them, but they are not passed as a location value to the booking...

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Changing the property works, thank you! But is there maybe a way to pass the Location object right away? this way I have to add a LocationId AND a Location property to the booking model and have to find the location via the passed id in the create and add to the booking, because I still need the location object/property later, not just the locationId

Comment: To get the entire object from view to Controller you need to render that objects properties in fields on view. With drop-down list thats not possible. Rendering all the objects of drop-down list will make the DOM heavy. so if it is not too much of a hassle to get the location details based on id, then you should stick with the approach I suggested. It also s standard and recommended way to collect selection via drop-down list or any other inputs which allows selection from multiple choices.

Comment: I also suggest to not retrieve all the information of location just to populate drop-down list. You need only locationID and city name to populate drop-down list. You should retrieve only these two columns to avoid unnecessary data retrieval.

Comment: Please show the Create POST action code.